# Spark-Scala XML Parsing

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I am parsing XML files with Spark and Scala. My XML files are located in the same directory and the only problem is that there are 2 type of XMLs that have different headers. The content of my XML´s looks something like this:

[image]

In my Spark code I am using 2 JobConf (JobCOnfigurations) to read the content of the XML because of the 2 different XML headers, TRN and TRNDFR. But the performance is very slow and I need to speed it up a little bit. The 2 JobConf that I am currently using look like this:

```
val jobConf = new JobConf()
jobConf.set("stream.recordreader.class", "org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamXmlRecordReader")
jobConf.set("stream.recordreader.begin", "< TRN")
jobConf.set("stream.recordreader.end", "< /TRN")

val jobConf2 = new JobConf()
jobConf.set("stream.recordreader.class", "org.apache.hadoop.streaming.StreamXmlRecordReader")
jobConf2.set("stream.recordreader.begin", "< TRNDFR ")
jobConf2.set("stream.recordreader.end", "< /TRNDFR>")
```

Therefore my question is that if it`s possible to create one single jobConf that can read both the headers TRN and TRNDFR? Does the stream.recordreader.begin allow to have two beginings such as TRN and TRNDFR as headers ? Could it be possible to use a regular expression in the stream.recordreader.begin?

Cheers

Comment: please don't paste _screenshots_ of code / data - paste the code itself, so that it's searchable and copy-paste-able.

Comment: Are you sure that you see performance degradation because you use two job confs? And what is this job conf, anyway?

Comment: As far as I know (and maybe Im mistaken) what the JobConf does is that it goes through all the inputs you specify in the spark-submit command and it extracts all the information that matches your stream.recordreader.begin/end flag and it permits you to save it afterwards in your RDDs. If I have 2 jobConf´s i infer that it will have to go twice over the input. Im not entirely sure if it would improve my performance but its worth a try at least!